# Disable a button onClick with Redux/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, ecmascript-6, redux

Im pretty new to redux & react; I want to disable a button onClick to prevent multiple copies of data being saved. My button is in the footer component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Footer = React.createClass({

  render () {
    const { save, saveAs, onLeave, edit, disableButtons } = this.props;

    return (
      <footer className="footer">
        <button onClick={ save.bind(this, onLeave) } className="btn btn-secondary">{__( 'Save' )}</button>
        { edit && <div onClick={ saveAs.bind(this, onLeave) }  className="btn btn-primary save-as">{__( 'Save As' )}</div> }
      </footer>
    )
  }
});

export default Footer;
```

In react redux I have the *actions* set up as:

```
export const SaveButton = bool => ({ type: ActionTypes.SAVE_BUTTON, bool})

export const SaveAsButton = bool => ({ type: ActionTypes.SAVE_AS_BUTTON, bool})
```

*Reducer*:

```
const disableButtons = ( state=false, action ) => {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case ActionTypes.SAVE_AUDIENCE:
      return action.bool
    case ActionTypes.SAVE_AS_AUDIENCE:
      return action.bool
  }
}
```

The MapDispatchToProps is done in the connect function in a higher level container:

```
export default connect(({ onLeave, edit, disableButtons }) => Object.assign({}, { onLeave, edit, disableButtons }), allActions)(Module);
```

How can I dispatch the saveButton/saveAsButton action to toggle whether the button is disabled in the footer component? Is this the wrong way to go about this? Thank you!

Comment: could u show ur mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps functions

Comment: Btw: Save yourself a huge future headache by using a form utility plugin, I recommend you to take a look at [Redux Form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/) ;-)